.NET Core - multiple span levels
I'm looking to convert an array of string to ReadOnlySpan<ReadOnlySpan<Char>> to optimize a split algorithm.
Is it possible? How?
string[] separators;

ReadOnlyChar<char> totalChars = stackalloc char[separators.Sum(s => s.Length)];

// Copy each string in continu

ReadOnlySpan<ReadOnlySpan<Char>> spanSeparators = stackalloc ReadOnlySpan<ReadOnlySpan<Char>>[separator.Length];

// Slice each string into 


Can you show what it is you are actually doing? There may be a better way as @MarcGravell alludes.

No. A span (or a ref-struct more generally) cannot be used as a generic type argument, and since the T in Span<T> is a generic type argument: this cannot work.
If the origin here is a string, you could do something involving Span<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>, though, using string.AsMemory (from MemoryExtensions). However, I wonder if a better approach is to create a custom iterator instead, i.e. don't actually precompute or store anything, and just do the work to find the next item (from the current state) in the MoveNext(). Since foreach works via duck-typing, it should work against a ref-struct iterator, allowing you to store a "working" span in a field.

broad sketch of the custom enumerator approach: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/a5cc87683198c0ce657c0b778a1a5e23

Incidentally there is a proposal for this https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/7608 as well as ref ref values https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13627

I like the custom iterator. I can make a generic iterator like span to move through a ReadOnlySpan. Creating a array of contigus memory
